# how to play video using html5 videoplayer in android phonegap?

Tags: html, cordova, html5-video

I have created application in android phonegap.I want to play video using html5 video player.
My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
          <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm' />
            <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
          </video>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This code show the videoplayer .but video is not playing while clicking play button.what's wrong?

please guide me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Android has issues with playing video and can often only be triggered via JavaScript by adding a click event handler to the video element and playing the video once that is activated.

For example:

```
function play() {
   var video = document.getElementById('video');
   video.addEventListener('click',function(){
      video.play();
   },false);
}
```

You will probably need to adapt this code to work with yours though.

Answer (score 1):

Everything immediately worked for me. I'm using an iOS emulator.

Make sure you set the permission to go to that URL.

```
Cordova.plist --> externalhosts
```

You can use a wildcard to cover several URL's into one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
data-setup='{"controls":true}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .I have used this "data-setup" but video is not played.please help me. how to play video using html5 video tag in android phonegap.please guide me.thanks in advance.

Comment: In my logat I am getting this error:ERROR/ActivityThread(212): Failed to find provider info for com.android.calendar.and ERROR/MediaPlayerService(34): Couldn't open fd for content://settings/system/notification_sound and  WARN/NotificationService(66): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000.please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your main Activity

```
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();

    this.appView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have added this code in my main activity.but video is not played while clicking play button.please guide me how to use html5 video tag for playing video in android phonegap.thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML looks fine. I have video working with very similar HTML and the code above to enable plugins. It would be difficult to help further without actually working on the app and looking at what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

We cant play video using  in android. it works fine in iphone though. try using plugin for the purpose.
check this out
[VideoPlayer Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/VideoPlayer)