# how to play a video in android emulator using phonegap?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-video-player

how to play a video in android emulator using phonegap?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#ytplayer").attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + getValue("id") +'?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com');
        $("#back").click(function(){
          window.location.href = "moves.html?day=" + getValue("day") + "&week=" + getValue("week") + "&tier=" + getValue("tier");

        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add some detail there. Have you tried to search on the web for this issue. Maybe this article on the blog can help you: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html

Comment: sir i have used every possibilities..i check http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/11/video-player-plugin-for-phonegap.html the link too..but still not working..plz help me...

Comment: Please add details. What exception or error msg are you getting. Also are you trying to run a video on YouTube from your Android app via phonegap or a local video from your app. Please specify.

Comment: You might need to use Javascript to play your video. Here is a possible duplicate to your question on this forum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702691/how-to-play-video-using-html5-videoplayer-in-android-phonegap

Comment: i use the coding that is perfectly playing in iphone and html alone i use the jscript too                                            <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and i use the in code

Comment: send me the exact type of coding that will play the video in android  using phonegay...specially $(document).ready(function()$("#ytplayer").attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + getValue("id") +'?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com');$("#back").click(function(){if( getValue("Stat")==1)
{window.location.href = "Stationary combos.html?Stat=" + getValue("Stat") + "&coach=" + getValue("coach");
}});
});